# Is there a way to make sure an autocomplete field as an actual match?

Tags: entities, ajax

I have an entity reference field in a content type in D7 set with an autocomplete widget. This is a required field, however if you type in something that doesn't have a match, it will still submit and save anyway.

Is there a way to make sure an actual match is found before allowing it to save?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty major bug in the entity reference module, are you absolutely sure you've tested this properly?

Comment: Here you go: https://drupal.org/node/1974202. Can you try that patch and report back? I know it's not exactly what you're asking about, but it seems quite related

Comment: Thanks Clive, this sounds right.  Testing the patch now.

Comment: That specific patch didn't fix my problem, but after reviewing the issues, this has actually been brought up a lot in:
https://drupal.org/project/issues/entityreference?text=autocomplete&status=All

I'll engage with the issue queue there about this.  Thanks for response @Clive

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments above, this is a bug with Entity Reference Fields and is being engaged per the Issue Queue at:

https://drupal.org/project/issues/entityreference?text=autocomplete&status=All

Patches for the Simple batch seem to work from this thread:
https://drupal.org/node/1974202

Patches for the Views reference seem to work from this thread:
https://drupal.org/node/1702172